# How can i get the name of the collection where an object belongs and store it into a variable

Tags: python, scripting, collections

How can i get the name of the collection where an object belongs and store the name of that collection into a variable so i can use it later to unlink the object from that collection

Comment: Objects don't "belong" to a single collection, they may be linked in several collections simultaneously. They may even be in different collections in do scenes at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bpy.types.Object.users_collection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.users_collection) attribute to retrieve the collections it is linked in. It's a sequence of collections which can contain 0 or more items, since an object can be part of 0 or more collections.

I'll assume your object is part of at least one collection since it's the general case.

```
obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]  # Replace with your object name

col = obj.users_collection[0]  # This stores a reference to the (first) collection
col_name = col.name
```

If your object is linked in several collections, you'll have to add custom logic since AFAIK the order in which they are stored in `users_collection` is not deterministic.